# AVAudioSession not working when receiving a VOIP/SIP Call on iOS. WebRTC | SIP

Tags: ios, webrtc, sip, avaudiosession

We have audio video calling feature in the application. When I make a call to an android device then both the sender and receiver can hear the voices. However, when the call is received at the iOS device, there is no sound of voice anywhere.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Or is it a iOS app?

Comment: its an iOS app @Maxi

Comment: More information is required to answer your question. Some helpful code or logs. Do you use a TURN server? Do you use a media server? etc.

Comment: Oh yes, We are using a TURN Server. We have also integrated PORTSip SDK as we have SIP calling as well. BTW, this is happening specifically when I'm using Callkit and the after reporting the call the sound doesn't work. I'll provide some more codes and information shortly. Thanks for holding on !!